# How to join points {x1,y1} and {x2,y2} only if x2-x1==1

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Given

```
list={{5, 3}, {9, 5}, {10, 4}, {11, 3}, {13, 3}, {14, 4}}
```

I want to `ListPlot` these points and use `Joined` only for those points where the x-values differ by one. So here I would get two line segments `{{9, 5}, {10, 4}, {11, 3}}` and  `{{13, 3}, {14, 4}}` . I tried to add conditions to `Joined` but could not get anywhere. I also want to `Plot` the single points left over. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) as follows:

```
RelationGraph[#2[[1]] == #[[1]] + 1 &, list, VertexCoordinates -> list]
```

[image]

```
rg = RelationGraph[#2[[1]] == #[[1]] + 1 &, list, 
  VertexCoordinates -> list,
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"], Opacity[.5], AbsoluteThickness[15]],
  EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line"]
```

[image]

We can get the pieces using [`WeaklyConnectedComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeaklyConnectedComponents.html)  and style the edges and vertices using [`VertexShapeFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexShapeFunction.html) and [`HighlightGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightGraph.html):

```
wcc = WeaklyConnectedComponents[rg];

SeedRandom[12]
vshapes = Thread[Alternatives @@@ wcc -> 
    RandomSample[GraphElementData["VertexShapeFunction"], Length @ wcc]];

HighlightGraph[SetProperty[rg, {VertexSize -> .1, VertexShapeFunction -> vshapes}], 
 Subgraph[rg, #] & /@ wcc, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {{5, 3}, {9, 5}, {10, 4}, {11, 3}, {13, 3}, {14, 4}};

list2 = Split[list, #2[[1]] - #1[[1]] == 1 &];

ListPlot[list2, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

or with [`PlotMarkers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html)

```
ListPlot[list2, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks! But I forgot to mention that I want to plot the single points, too.

Comment: @user57467 Please add that requirement to the question!

Comment: "I want to `ListPlot` these points" seems clear enough to me.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `FindClusters`

```
FindClusters[{{5, 3}, {9, 5}, {10, 4}, {11, 3}, {13, 3}, {14, 4}}, 3, 
DistanceFunction -> (Abs[#1 - #2][[1]] &)]
```

> {{{5, 3}}, {{9, 5}, {10, 4}, {11, 3}}, {{13, 3}, {14, 4}}}